# Find all triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $(c, c^2)$ is a point on the graph.

Tags: calculus

Find all triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that $(c, c^2)$ is a point on the graph of $y = x^2$ with minimum sum of distances to $(0, a)$ and $(0, b)$.

I am seeking hints for this problem. Thank you

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9003)

Comment: Please provide more details to the problem and your attempt so others can help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I am interpreting the question correctly, so correct if wrong.

Say you have chosen $(a,b,c)$. Then either the distance between $(0,a)$ and $(c,c^2)$ or $(0,b)$ and $(c,c^2)$ will be the minimum. If they tie, just pick either. Suppose it is $a$ that was the minimum. Then $(a,a,c)$ will have a smaller sum of distances.

So the quantity you are trying to minimize is

$$
G = 2 dist((0,a),(c,c^2))\\
$$

Minimize it's square.

$$
G^2 = 4 dist((0,a),(c,c^2))^2\\
= 4 (c^2 + (c^2-a)^2)\\
$$

Now consider what happens as you increase $c$ but leave $a$ fixed and vice versa.